# Generate Unique Long ID for a view in MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, view, auto-generate

I have a view over three tables. It has 6 columns as follows:

```
ID | NAME | PRINCIPAL_ID | DESCRIPTION | GROUP_ID | TYPE
```

As I'm using `hibernate` to retrieve data from database, I had to put the `ID` column in this view. The problem is, I cannot generate a unique `ID` which seems to be necessary for `hibernate` to correctly load the data.

How can I have a unique ID for every row in this view?

*Maybe this can help, I'm not sure*: The combination of `PRINCIPAL_ID` and `GROUP_ID` can make a unique ID. All these three are `Long`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE: When you insist to have it as a number, create your view like this:

```
SELECT
(@rownum:=@rownum + 1) AS rownumber,
yourTable.*
FROM
yourTable
, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

But that's really it - no more other possibilities. Cast rownumber as `long` like I said in comments, if it really, really has to be `long`.

Alternatively in a [procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-procedure.html):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE selectFromWhatever()
BEGIN
SELECT
(@rownum:=@rownum + 1) AS rownumber,
yourTable.*
FROM
yourTable
, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then get result with

```
CALL selectFromWhatever()
```

**Original answer:**

From the MySQL manual:

**[UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)**

> Returns a Universal Unique Identifier (UUID) generated according to
>   “DCE 1.1: Remote Procedure Call” (Appendix A) CAE (Common Applications
>   Environment) Specifications published by The Open Group in October
>   1997 (Document Number C706,
>   http://www.opengroup.org/public/pubs/catalog/c706.htm).
>
> A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and
>   time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different
>   values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers
>   that are not connected to each other.
>
> A UUID is a 128-bit number represented by a utf8 string of five
>   hexadecimal numbers in aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee format:
>
> The first three numbers are generated from a timestamp.
>
> The fourth number preserves temporal uniqueness in case the timestamp value loses monotonicity (for example, due to daylight
>   saving time).
>
> The fifth number is an IEEE 802 node number that provides spatial uniqueness. A random number is substituted if the latter is not
>   available (for example, because the host computer has no Ethernet
>   card, or we do not know how to find the hardware address of an
>   interface on your operating system). In this case, spatial uniqueness
>   cannot be guaranteed. Nevertheless, a collision should have very low
>   probability.
>
> Currently, the MAC address of an interface is taken into account only on FreeBSD and Linux. On other operating systems, MySQL uses a
>   randomly generated 48-bit number.
>
> mysql> SELECT UUID();
>           -> '6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29'
>
> Warning
>
> Although UUID() values are intended to be unique, they are not
>   necessarily unguessable or unpredictable. If unpredictability is
>   required, UUID values should be generated some other way. Note
>
> UUID() does not work with statement-based replication.

**Another way** would be to use `CONCAT()` to build your unique ID.

```
SELECT CONCAT(PRINCIPAL_ID, '-', GROUP_ID) AS myUniqueID
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: can I use it multiple times? Does it generate a `Long` value?

Comment: Of course you can use it multiple times. No it does not generate a `long` value.

Comment: So, as I understood this is generating unique value each time. The problem is I need a `Long` value for the ID. How is that possible using this `UUID`?

Comment: When I use it (for creating the view) it gives me an error. Sounds like I should not use a variable when creating a view.

Comment: This is giving me this error, when used in creating a view `view's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`

Comment: @MatinKh Ah, sorry, forgot about that. Then you have to make it a procedure. Which comes with certain restrictions. Maybe it would be easier if you told me, why it has to be `long`. Why is UUID() not appropriate? There is no way, you can make a unique `long` value out of three `long` columns. The easiest solution would be to just have an auto_increment column in your table. Tell me if you need to know how to accomplish that.

Comment: You're right. Just put a link on `how to write a procedure` and your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS ROW_NUM ... COLUMN... FROM TABLE
```