# Selecting row count to use as arbitrary row ID

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm trying to alter a current mysql view I have so that when I export the view I have a unique row ID.

I'm trying to find a way to possibly use the row number or an auto increment function but I don't know how to do this in a view.

Here is the query:

```
alter view daily_report as SELECT 
@id := @id + 1 as id
,c.extension as Extension
,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
, sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound   
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inbound
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
, count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
, NOW()
, curdate()
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
        ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
      ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0 ) as var
WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
group by c.extension;
```

Is there a way to use row count or something in my select statement so that my view has unique row IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user variables

```
 SELECT @id := @id + 1 as id, <other field>
 FROM ( <your tables> )
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0 ) as var
```

Comment: So I would put parenthesis around all my current code after from and then do the cross JOIN?

Comment: Nope. Just add the `CROSS JOIN` at the end of your `FROM` tables and before the `WHERE`

Comment: Ok, that fixed the syntax errors, I updated with the new query but now I get an error that my SELECT contains variable or parameter?

Comment: This is a view, so would I have to alter this slightly?

Comment: Looks like you cant use variables in a view. Either try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891993/create-a-view-with-column-num-rows-mysql or use a sproc instead of a view like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621924/generate-unique-long-id-for-a-view-in-mysql